# Ruby Guessing Game w 'Loop Do'

Tags: ruby, terminal, atom-editor

I created a guessing game through Ruby and I believe the structure of my code is off. When entering 'Cheat', you are given the random number then asked to type it in again. When typed in again, it says the random number is not correct and always defaults to my 'elseif' in line 45.

```
puts "Hey! I'm Sam. What's your name?"
name = gets
puts "Welcome #{name}. Thanks for playing the guessing game.
I've chosen a number between 1-100.
You'll have 10 tries to guess the correct number.
You'll also recieve a hint when you're guess is wrong.
If you feel like being a big ol cheater, type 'Cheat'.
Let's get started..."

random_number = rand(1...100)
Cheat = random_number
counter = 10

loop do
 break if counter == 0
 divisor = rand(2...10)
 guess = gets.chomp
  break if guess.to_i == random_number
 counter -= 1
 if
   guess == random_number
   puts 'You guessed the right number! You win!'
 end
 if counter < 4
   puts "You can go ahead and cheat by typing 'Cheat'..."
 end
  if guess.to_s.downcase.eql? "cheat"
    puts "The random number is #{random_number} you CHEATER!! Go ahead and type it in..."
    guess = gets.chomp
    puts = "You win cheater!"
  end
 if
     guess.to_i < random_number
     puts 'Ah shucks, guess again!'
     guess = gets.chomp
 elsif
     guess.to_i > random_number
     puts 'Too high, guess again!'
     guess = gets.chomp
 end

 if random_number % divisor == 0
   puts "Thats not it.\n #{guess} is #{guess.to_i > random_number ? 'less' : 'greater'} than the random number.
   The random number is divisible by #{divisor}.\nTry again: "
 elsif
   puts "That's not the random number.\n #{guess} is #{guess.to_i > random_number ? 'less' : 'greater'} than the random number.
   The random number is NOT divisible by #{divisor}.\nTry again: "
 end
end

if counter > 0
  puts "The number is #{random_number}! You win!"
else
  puts "You lose! Better luck another time."
end
```

this is the response i get in the terminal

```
Let's get started...
Cheat
The random number is 96 you CHEATER!! Go ahead and type it in...
96
Thats not it.
 96 is greater than the random number.
   The random number is divisible by 8.
Try again:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
puts = "You win cheater!"
```

You're assigning the string `"You win cheater!"` to a local variable named `puts`. Changing it to this fixes the problem:

```
puts "You win cheater!"
```

You'll probably also want to put a `break` after that line.

---

As an aside, this pattern:

```
loop do
  break if counter == 0
  # ...
end
```

...would be better expressed as:

```
while counter > 0
  # ...
end
```

...or:

```
until counter == 0
  # ...
end
```

---

Also, you should *always* put the condition for an `if`/`elsif`/whathaveyou on the same line as `if` et al. Why? Because if you don't you get bugs like this:

```
if random_number % divisor == 0
  # ...
elsif
  puts "..."
end
```

Can you spot the bug? You forgot to put a condition after `elsif`, or used `elsif` when you meant to use `else`, which means that the return value of `puts` (which is always `nil`) is being used as the condition, just as if you had written `elsif puts "..."`.

If you make a habit of always putting the condition on the same line as `if`/`elsif`, your eye will get used to it and errors like this will jump out at you.

Comment: thanks! I noticed a few mistakes thanks to you. Appreciate the help!